# Do typos or grammatical errors in titles warrant an edit more than ones in the body?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

I know that edit significance has been brought up several times here on Meta, and that the consensus so far is that an edit that only improves on a few typos is too minor. However, does a typo in the question's title [like this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/133167/revisions) increase the need for an edit? The title is, after all, the eyecatch for the post and should as such be, well, beautiful.

Are errors in question titles grounds for edits more than ones in the body?

Perhaps a "minor edit" checkbox should be added to the edits page, for easier moderation of suggested edits and perhaps lesser visual significance on the revisions page? Or is that overly complicated?

Comment: My eye is twitching. I know its intentional to raise the point, but I can't help it

Comment: I couldn't tolerate it anymore. This is unacceptable.

Comment: @kalina Oh COME ON. This is unacceptable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The title is important, fixing any error in the title is a good enough reason to edit a question, even if it is older. Fixing a typo or bad grammar in the title is never too minor of an edit, unless you ignore obvious problems in the post body.

But that doesn't mean one should stop editing at the title, you should always try to fix *all* problems that a post has.

Comment: Of course, when you've started editing you might as well fix everything that needs to be fixed. Just a question of whether it calls for an edit in the first place, which you answered neatly.

Answer (score 12):

It's worth noting that the minor/major edit distinction is only relevant to making suggested edits before you have full edit privileges. We don't have any policy about what is too minor for full editors, since they are assumed to have developed the discretion to judge whether a post benefits from an edit or not, regardless of the number of letters it changes.

So yes, for suggested edits, it's still worth making edits to the title since it's a very important part of a question. However, there is no reason to alter the system to make that easier, since we already have a system in place for fixing titles easily: users with full edit privileges will take care of it soon enough. If you can't find anything else to fix in a post so that the system thinks it's a big enough edit, just don't worry about it. Someone will take care of it.

Comment: As a caveat/corollary: if a minor edit is *that important*, (say, a misspelled proper name/technical term that drastically impacts meaning or searchability) **and** the question is old/inactive (not on the front page, etc), **and** you're below 2K rep, **and** there's nothing else to fix: use a flag, or bother someone in chat. The number of conditionals there should make clear that this won't need to happen often.

Comment: Let it be known that @LessPop_MoreFizz has volunteered to take all these scenarios :)